# Cloning 14in Macbook Pro M1 Pro => 13in Macbook Air M2

Tags: hard-drive, backup, homebrew

I'll be traveling for the next few months and have got the chance to swap out my machine from a (IMO quite weighty) 2022 MacBook Pro 14in (M1 Pro) to a new 13in MacBook Air M2.

I'm a bit short on time and wondering if I can avoid starting the reinstall from scratch. I have the basics: Chrome, Sublime Text, Slack etc, alongside a MAMP install over Homebrew.

Is there an efficient solution to clone Mac to Mac? Are these Apple Silicon processors similar enough to clone properly? Or am I going to end up with a hot mess?

What clone solution would you use?

I've never taken the clone route before, as I get the benefit of wiping/installing from scratch to have a cleaner machine to get started with, but this might be a time saver here.

Comment: you would not clone but use the Apple Migration Assistant located in the Utility folder

Comment: Can't you use CCC (via an intermediary USB disk) to copy the file system from one mac to the other? That's what I've always done.

Comment: @Greenonline that's what I'm asking, will a CCC clone produce a usable system considering differences in CPU etc?

Comment: You can use a CCC backup (I wouldn't call it a clone) or a TM backup on a USB disk. Migration Assistant can use a suitable configured CCC backup or a TM backup as its source.

Comment: Best (but not essential) to make sure source and destination are running the same version of macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the Apple Migration Assistant that is made just for what you want.

Use Migration Assistant to copy all of your documents, apps, user accounts, and settings to a new Mac from another computer.

Find the instructions here

[Migrate](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350)

Comment: Would this also take care of everything installed via homebrew (inc homebrew itself) ?

Comment: @Dan everything but the OS it self

Comment: @Ruskes Does Migration Assistant really copy the content of `/opt` as well?

Comment: Thanks all, I can confirm that Migration assistant brought everything over, including Homebrew and the contents of `/opt`. The only downside is that it brought over my very untidy Desktop too :S.

Comment: For posterity's sake, Migration Assistant reckoned that my Wifi6 connection was faster than the Apple USB-C cable I had hanging around. If I did this in future, I'd probably grab a proper Thunderbolt cable to make it zippier.

Comment: @nohillside confirmed-- `Migration assistant brought everything over, including Homebrew and the contents of /opt`